# Dynamically change number of dots in a textview based on screentype

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a rather odd question. I'm creating an application where I display a list to the user, in the following format :

```
var1................... var2
var3................... var4
etc
```

The problem is : How can i change the number of dots based on the users screensize? Should I solve this using different layouts or dimens in /res, or is there an easier way to do it by code? I can't quiet figure this one out. Any hints, or tricks would be appreciated.

Some picture, to further demonstrate the problem, first one on the Nexus 4 preview :

[image: Nexus 4 preview]

And, a 3.7 FWVGA preview, clearly illustrates the problem, where the amount of dots should be decreased.

[image]

Comment: Use layout_weight to keep your textview within the screen on different devices

Comment: Would this cause an overlap of the dots, if the screensize is small?

Comment: no... weight means you would specify how much space it would take as percentage depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply position your two text boxes to extreme right and extreme left, in a RelativeLayout container by setting allignParentLeft & allighnParentRight properties. Then place a textView having lots of dots(any number 100/500),Set this textView toRightOf and toLeftOf properties, so that it is limited within the space of two inflammatory text boxes.

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GridLayout:

1st column the label text, 2nd the data.

Add android:layout_gravity="left" to the 2nd column, so the 1st column will get stretched as it has no gravity.